# Is there a way to read stdout in python?

Tags: python, io, stdout

What i want is to get all the text that i wrote in stdout as a string.

```
from sys import stdout

stdout.read()  # throws io.UnsupportedOperation: not readable
```

Example of what i want to get:

```
print("abc")
stdout.read() == "abc"  # True
```

Answer (score 1):

No.  As the documentation says, `stdout` is not readable.  Think of it as sending information to a physical printer.  For instance, when you send a page of text to your FAX-printer-scanner device, how would your program be able to read that output?  The characters are sent to an output buffer, down to the physical device, and flushed out to the paper.

The canonical way to handle this is with logging, which has several support packages in most mature languages, including Python.  You create a logger whose `log` method (write the output) echoes its input to both `print` and another store of your creation.  You add a `read` method to give you access to that store.

This gives you a little research to do and some coding work, but I trust you can start from here.  Look for the `logger` tutorials on line.  Of course, if you get stuck with that coding, you can post your example on Stack Overflow.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using 3.4 or higher, there is this recipe found in the documentation for contextlib

```
f = io.StringIO()
with contextlib.redirect_stdout(f):
   ... stuff ...

result = f.getvalue()
```

Note that the effect on stdout is global, so don't use it in libraries or in a threaded application.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use `logger`, you could create a custom print function:

```
from io import StringIO

printstore = StringIO()

def myprint(*args, **kwargs):
    print(*args, **kwargs) # unmodified print
    kwargs["file"] = printstore
    print(*args, **kwargs) # print to StringIO
```

This has the advantage that you get all the flexibility of the builtin `print`.
A drawback is that it catches only output printed with `myprint`.