# How do I get the contents of the console window?

Tags: python, terminal

I'm trying to get what is currently in the console window in a Python script.

For example;

```
print('Bar')
print('Foo')
print('\n')
print([variable I'm asking for])
```

Expected outcome:

```
Bar
Foo

Bar
Foo
```

But also:

```
os.system('dir')
print([the variable I'm asking for])
```

with the expected outcome:

```
[directories]
[directories]
```

I've tried the following (from [in python, get the output of system command as a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19243020/in-python-get-the-output-of-system-command-as-a-string)):

```
import subprocess
print('test1')
print('test2\n')
proc = subprocess.Popen('ls', stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
cmdstr = proc.stdout.read()
print(cmdstr)
```

and expected something like this:

```
test1
test2

test1
test2
```

but I got this:

```
test1
test2

'ls' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
b''
```

I've found this somewhere:

```
import sys
from io import StringIO

sys.stdout = temporarystd = StringIO() # redirect stdout

# stuff here

sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__ # return stdout to its old state

print(temporarystd.getvalue())
```

This worked fine for `print()` but I try to use os commands and those still go to the terminal.

Anyone knows why?

(Also, as mentioned by @dump-eldor; `'ls'` in `proc = subprocess.Popen('ls', stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)` should've been `'dir'`.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to read stdout in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63875536/is-there-a-way-to-read-stdout-in-python) also see: [Can I redirect the stdout into some sort of string buffer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1218933/can-i-redirect-the-stdout-into-some-sort-of-string-buffer)

Answer (score 1):

it looks like you run the program from windows os?if so try "dir" instead of "ls"